ADALINE simple implementation with 2 features bug
I am reading Machine Learning with PyTorch and Ski-kit learn book by Sebastian Raschka
While plotting the decision boundary (a line in this case, since the number of features considered = 2) I can't find the bug in my code.
Adaline implementation:
import numpy as np

class AdalineGD:
    """Adaptive Linear Neuron classifier

    Parameters
    ------------
    eta : float
        Learning rate between 0.0 and 1.0
    
    n_iter : int
        Number of iterations over the training dataset

    random_state : int
        Random number generator seed for random weight initialization

    Attributes:
    ------------

    w_ : 1d-array
        Weights after fitting
    
    b_ : scalar
        Bias
    
    errors : list
        Mean squared loss error in each epoch/iteration 
    
    """

    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=50, random_state=1) -> None:
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.random_state = random_state

    def fit(self, X, y):
        """Fit the training data
        
        Parameters
        ------------
        X : {array-like}, shape = [n_examples, n_features]
            Training vectors, where n_examples is the number of
            examples and n_features is the number of features.

        y : {array-like}, shape = [n_examples]
            Target values.

        Returns
        ------------
        self : object

        """
        rgen = np.random.RandomState(self.random_state)

        self.w_ = rgen.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.01, size=X.shape[1])
        self.b_ = np.float_(0.0)
        self.losses_ = []

        for i in range(self.n_iter):
            net_input = self.net_input(X)
            # the identity function used as the activation function on the net_input
            output = self.activation(net_input)

            errors = (y - output) # size : (n_examples, 1)

            # update the weights and bias
            self.w_ += self.eta * 2.0 * X.T.dot(errors) / X.shape[0]
            self.b_ += self.eta * 2.0 * errors.mean()
            
            # calculate loss for the iteration
            loss = (errors**2).mean() # mean squared error loss
            print(f'At iter : {i} -> loss : {loss}')

            # keep track of loss for iteration
            self.losses_.append(loss)

        return self
    
    def net_input(self, X):
        return np.dot(X, self.w_) + self.b_
    
    def activation(self, X):
        """Compute Linear activation"""
        return X

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.where(self.activation(self.net_input(X)) >= 0.5 , 1, 0)

Loading iris dataset and plotting the parameters $w_1 , w_2$ and $b$
using the equation $$w_1*x_1 + w_2*x_2 + b = 0$$
Solving for $x_2$ :
$$x_2 = (\frac{-w_1}{w_2}) * x_1 - (\frac{b}{w_2})$$
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from perceptron import Perceptron
from adaline import AdalineGD
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

data, target = load_iris(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

y = target.iloc[0:100]
y = np.where(y == 0, 0, 1) # considering 2 classes
X = data.iloc[0:100, [0,2]].values # 2 features [col 0, col 2]

agd = AdalineGD(eta=0.01, n_iter=50)
agd.fit(X, y)
print(agd.w_, agd.b_)


X1_min = X[:, 0].min()
X1_max = X[:, 0].max()

x1 = np.linspace(X1_min, X1_max, 100)
x2 = (-(agd.w_[0]/agd.w_[1]) * x1 ) - (agd.b_ / agd.w_[1])

#plot the training data
plt.scatter(X[0:50, 0], X[0:50, 1] , color='red', marker='o', label='Setosa') # X[0:50, 0] 50 examples of feature 1 (col = 0) plotted with X[0:50, 1] 50 examples of feature 2 (col 1)
plt.scatter(X[50:, 0], X[50:, 1] , color='blue', marker='s', label='Versicolor')

#plot the line (which is the decision function)
plt.plot(x1,x2)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length [cm]')
plt.ylabel('Petal length [cm]')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

Clearly, the line isn't separating the two classes. What am I doing wrong?

